# If life insurance is forbidden, then how is working at a mortgage company which takes commission and interest justified?

Tags: work

I work for a mortgage company which makes it money from commission and interest. But my job title is related to the web, and all I do is on the web. Lately, I been in an argument with my spouse, as she wants to stop a life insurance policy that has her name as beneficiary if something happens to me, because, according to her, it's not allowed in Islam. Thus...

If life insurance is forbidden, then how is working at a mortgage company which takes commission and interest justified?

Comment: There are already many questions of this sort. Please take some time to search for those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request to discredit your wife, not to learn about Islam.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many points and details concerning your question, since it’s not solely consists of one part. Let’s indicate some related points concerning that in short based on my limited knowledge.

- Life insurance money is forbidden? On the whole, it doesn’t seem to be haram as just a sort of insurance if at first, it is paid amount of money … then, the insurance supports the individuals which have insurance.
- Generally, working in insurance company doesn’t seem haram. Unless it could be haram or forbidden if you infer from its conditions that it consists of Riba or other haram acts. Since as you possibly are aware, there are several verse in the holy Qur’an concerning the Hormah or being haram (forbiddance) of Riba. For instance you can see the verses below regarding Riba.

> وَمَا آتَيْتُم مِّن رِّبًا لِّيَرْبُوَ فِي أَمْوَالِ النَّاسِ فَلَا
> يَرْبُو عِندَ اللَّـهِ ۖ وَمَا آتَيْتُم مِّن زَكَاةٍ تُرِيدُونَ وَجْهَ
> اللَّـهِ فَأُولَـٰئِكَ هُمُ الْمُضْعِفُونَ ﴿٣٩
>
> And whatever you give for interest to increase within the wealth of
> people will not increase with Allah. But what you give in zakah,
> desiring the countenance of Allah - those are the multipliers. (39)
> (Ar-Rum)
>
> ---
>
> وَأَخْذِهِمُ الرِّبَا وَقَدْ نُهُوا عَنْهُ وَأَكْلِهِمْ أَمْوَالَ
> النَّاسِ بِالْبَاطِلِ ۚ وَأَعْتَدْنَا لِلْكَافِرِينَ مِنْهُمْ عَذَابًا
> أَلِيمًا ﴿١٦١
>
> And [for] their taking of usury while they had been forbidden from it,
> and their consuming of the people's wealth unjustly. And we have
> prepared for the disbelievers among them a painful punishment. (161)
> (An-Nisa)

---

**References:**

- [tanzil.net (1)](https://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/4:161)
- [tanzil.net (2)](http://tanzil.net/#30:39)
- [www.hawzah.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20150706013528/http://www.hawzah.net:80/fa/Article/View/92498/)
- [www.alipakzad.com](http://alipakzad.com/%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%9F/)